# how to send uri to facebook in the right format

Tags: facebook, dns

I need help on facebook login wth app. I have a website http://отдых-сицилия.рф. I did configured this in facebook app, and I am trying to login from my application.

I have the code below:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'code', // App ID
    channelUrl : '//отдых-сицилия.рф/channel.php', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });     
  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app. 

    // FB.login({scope:'email,hometown'});  
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {             
          document.getElementById('nome').value = response.name;
          if(response.email){
            document.getElementById('email').value = response.email;  
          } 
          document.getElementById('fbusername').value = response.username;  
          document.getElementById('fbname').value = response.first_name;
          document.getElementById('fbsurname').value = response.last_name; 
          document.getElementById('nazionalita').value = response.locale; 
          if(response.hometown){
            document.getElementById('citta').value = response.hometown.name;  
          }                    
      });         
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.             
      FB.login({scope:'email,hometown'});
    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.              
      FB.login({scope:'email,hometown'});
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
```

this code works very good on other 2 websites.

What I noticed is that when I open the login popup, the url is:

```
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Freturn%2Farbiter%3Frelation%3Dopener%26close%3Dtrue%23origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252F%25D0%25BE%25D1%2582%25D0%25B4%25D1%258B%25D1%2585-%25D1%2581%25D0%25B8%25D1%2586%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F.%25D1%2580%25D1%2584%252Ff32358e929d241c&app_id={APP_ID}&display=popup
```

so, the website url is not correct. How can I pass this url correctly?Or what cand I do?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to login anyway, and see if the user is redirected to your website? It may appear incorrect (since it's URL encoded) but does it work?

Comment: Your domain "отдых-сицилия.рф" is the next generation (I don't know how could you register it!?, since ICANN still testing those domains), which facebook can NOT handle it!

Comment: Yes, I tried to login anyway but it doesn't work. So, Adam, you are saying that facebook cannot handle this domains?